# E2E test an Outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have an Outlook add-in in the AppSource but are hoping to add automated tests to it to ensure no regressions during active development, since it is live already.

Is there any tooling provided by Microsoft for automated e2e testing of an Outlook add-in or any recommended ways to do this easily?

Since the add-in is just a web app, we considered running it separately but we'd be missing the entire Outlook context on the window... are there any test/mock objects for this either?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev's answer is very helpful and seems like the right approach. Are you trying to automate your add-in by mocking the Outlook context so that you don't have to manually open Outlook and trigger your add-in to run your tests?

Comment: Yea, we didn't want to have to run the tests by opening Outlook in the browser. We want to run automated tests on a variety of environments - sure we could set up a test account and then manually install different versions of our add-in based on environment, but was wondering if there was anyway to mock instead and not rely on Outlook context. or some sort of testing environment, etc.

Comment: Tooling would be helpful here to mock Outlook. There are a variety of tools that could help you achieve this. To add to Eugene's answer, you could look into AutoIt: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/, but there is no recommended tooling for mocking Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook web add-ins are just regular web applications. There is no recommended tooling provided by Microsoft for that. You can choose whatever suits your needs best.

You may consider combining UI Automation code with Selenium to cover the desktop edition of Outlook with web browsers.